# Random Forest, high test data error but zero training data error

Tags: random-forest

So the issue I'm having is that with the code below I have a very high training accuracy but my testing accuracy is only nearing 50%. This also goes for different amounts of trees which leads me to believe that my model is either faulty or I'm doing something wrong.

In the original document I have all necessary libraries imported. (it's a notebook)

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrongly here?

> Train_data shape = 300,30

> Test_data shape = 300,1

```
number_of_trees = 1000
size_of_bag = 200
np.random.seed(1)   # Allows for a deterministic outcome

# M datasets of ^N datapoints of original N dataset -> ^N subset of N -> M uniformly sampled sets of ^N 

def fit_tree_on_bag(train_data: np.ndarray, train_labels: np.ndarray, size_of_bag: int) -> DecisionTreeClassifier:
    """
    Fits a tree and returns predictions of train and test data
    
    :param train_data: training data inputs (shape N x D)
    :param train_labels: training data labels, which are -1 or 1 (shape N x 1)
    :param size_of_bag: size of the bag
    :return: a DecisionTreeClassifier object
    """
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

    indices = np.arange(train_data.shape[0])
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
    train_data_shuff = train_data[indices]
    train_labels_shuff = train_labels[indices]
    
    tree = DecisionTreeClassifier()
    tree = tree.fit(train_data_shuff[:size_of_bag],train_labels_shuff[:size_of_bag])

    return tree

trees = [fit_tree_on_bag(train_data, train_labels, size_of_bag) for _ in range(number_of_trees)]

def evaluate_ensemble(trees: List[DecisionTreeClassifier], data: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Obtain predictions for the ensemble (aggregating predictions of individual trees)
    
    :param trees: list of DecisionTreeClassifier objects
    :param data: data inputs (shape N x D)
    :return: ensemble prediction
        Note: prediction values should be either -1 or 1
    """
    output = []
    

    for row in range(data.shape[0]):
      #refresh output_array every row.
      output_array = []
      for tree in trees:
        predict = tree.predict(data[row, :].reshape(1,-1))
        output_array.append(int(predict))

      unique, counts = np.unique(output_array, return_counts=True)
      output.append(unique[np.argmax(counts)])
    
    return output

# Make final prediction
output_train = evaluate_ensemble(trees, train_data)
output_test = evaluate_ensemble(trees, test_data)

# Print accuracies
print('Bagging with {0} trees, Train Accuracy:{1: .3f} %'.format(number_of_trees, calculate_accuracy(train_labels, output_train)*100))
print('Bagging with {0} trees, Test Accuracy: {1: .3f} %'.format(number_of_trees, calculate_accuracy(test_labels, output_test)*100))
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any issue in your code, and thus assume the problem lies in the test/train data split. Did you [stratify](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#stratification) your split

High test error but great performance on training data could be explained by:

- [overfitting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395197/overfitting-and-underfitting)
- different distribution of samples across test / training dataset
- class imbalance

Even with your spotless code, you could still face this.

### Next Steps

Investigate sample distribution for both test and train data. Plot the distribution of target values for both.
You might also enjoy reading:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111968/random-forest-how-to-handle-overfitting

Comment: I have used 5 fold cross validation before. I'll give it a shot and I'll read the last link you referred me too.

Comment: I closed my notebook, opened it again and apparently my test accuracy is now 94%. This is odd.

Comment: Unless you share the whole notebook, or specifically the part where you split and preprocess data, I am not able to provide more help.

Comment: Found out that the issue was that I had previously edited variables that I re-used later in the program. By doing so I always worked with the same wrongly formatted dataset. Later reruns confirmed this.